# Qlikview Fixed values in bar graph and

Tags: qlikview

Hello i have a question in qlikview

How I can set fixed values ​​in a bar graph?

and

How is the expression to make 3 buttons that display the data from the last year, month and week?

I have that dimensions (In Spanish->English)

FECHA CREACION DATE START
FECHA CIERRE  DATE FINISH
Semana -> Week

Comment: Firstly, what do you mean set fixed values in a bar graph? The idea of a graph is that the values fluctuate. Do you mean you want to limit your dimensions?

Comment: Secondly, displaying data from the last year, month and week depends entirely on your data structure.

Comment: If you just set an Expression to "100" then its becomes a fixed value across all dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

To create a button that selects week or month create a trigger with following code:

> Month
>
> ='>='&MonthStart(Today())&'<='&MonthEnd(Today())
>
> Week
>
> ='>='&WeekStart(Today())&'<='&WeekEnd(Today())